# Sending message to multiple device in gcm

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I need to check the time taken by my java app to send the message to GCM.
i have seven reg id for my android app(emulator).
I need to check the time taken to send 700 devices for one message.
I gave the same 7 reg id for 100 times in an array to send gcm. Total time took only 3 secs.
Even for 100 devices im getting same time(3 secs).
Will GCM takes same time for any number of device?
or
I did in a wrong way?

Comment: how can we know? Are you using batch request? or one by one?

Comment: 3 seconds is a very long time except if your connection is bad: http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/10/part-ii-how-to-implement-gcm-php-push.html

Comment: My experience as stated; It should take less than 1 seconds on a 10mbs connection. You must have some overhead somewhere. The proof is that 100 and 700 are both taking 3 sec!

Comment: k thats not a prob, i want to know either to send 100 or 800 device in a single batch, will it take same amount of time?

Comment: Well, to be precise, no: You are transmitting more data (x8) and at the same time receiving more data (x8). Therefore, it needs more time. However, it is in the order of 10s milliseconds on modern connections.